# MySQL error - #1062 - Duplicate entry ' ' for key 2

Tags: mysql, database

I'm trying to insert a huge list of users to a MySQL database but everytime I try I get the error:

```
#1062 - Duplicate entry '' for key 2
```

It gives me this because the 2nd column is blank on quite a lot of the entries, so after it's inserted one blank entry in column 2, it won't let me add another. However, when I added most of the list yesterday I didn't get this error once even though a lot of the entries I added yesterday have a blank cell in column 2 as well. Whats going on?

This is the sql code to insert 1 entry. The rest follow the same format:

```
INSERT INTO users
  (`id`,`title`,`firstname`,`lastname`,`company`,`address`,`city`,`county`
   ,`postcode`,`phone`,`mobile`,`category`,`email`,`password`,`userlevel`) 
VALUES     
  ('','','John','Doe','company','Streeet','city','county'
  ,'postcode','phone','','category','emial@email.co.uk','','');
```

Comment: Wasn't an unique index added?

Comment: Do a `SHOW CREATE TABLE` on that table so we can see the schema.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In addition to Sabeen's answer:

The first column id is your primary key.
Don't insert `''` into the primary key, but insert null instead.

```
INSERT INTO users
  (`id`,`title`,`firstname`,`lastname`,`company`,`address`,`city`,`county`
   ,`postcode`,`phone`,`mobile`,`category`,`email`,`password`,`userlevel`) 
VALUES     
  (null,'','John','Doe','company','Streeet','city','county'
  ,'postcode','phone','','category','emial@email.co.uk','','');
```

If it's an autoincrement key this will fix your problem.
If not make `id` an autoincrement key, and always insert `null` into it to trigger an autoincrement.

MySQL has a setting to autoincrement keys only on `null` insert or on both inserts of `0` and `null`. Don't count on this setting, because your code may break if you change server.
If you insert `null` your code will always work.

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

Comment: Just for my own confirmation, i just tried '' on a primary auto-increment column and the query went thru just fine and mysql automatically put in the correct auto-increment value. Can you show me some reference for what you have said, want to make sure i keep that in mind the next time.

Comment: @Sabeen, From this page: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html: `How AUTO_INCREMENT behaves depending on the NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO SQL mode: Section 5.1.6, “Server SQL Modes”.`

Comment: @Johan, These settings are more harmful than helpful. I wonder why they even bothered adding them into MySQL.

Answer (score 11):

Seems like the second column is set as a unique index. If you dont need that remove it and your errors will go away. Possibly you added the index by mistake and thats why you are seeing the errors today and werent seeing them yesterday

Comment: thanks. you were right. it was to do with a unique column. I was just being tired and retarded and completely missed it. thanks for jogging my memory :)

Comment: @Sabeen, -1 because it's not the 2nd column, but the first. `''` gets translated into 0 and if MySQL is not set to trigger autoincrement on 0 insert, it will duplicate insert 0, see my answer below.

Comment: @Johan ... the op said `It gives me this because the 2nd column is blank on quite a lot of the entries, so after it's inserted one blank entry in column 2, it won't let me add another.` .. so i am taking his word for it

Comment: I figured OP had: NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO set to true.

Answer (score 2):

I got this error when I tried to set a column as unique when there was already duplicate data in the column OR if you try to add a column and set it as unique when there is already data in the table.

I had a table with 5 rows and I tried to add a unique column and it failed because all 5 of those rows would be empty and thus not unique.

I created the column without the unique index set, then populated the data then set it as unique and everything worked.

Answer (score 1):

As it was said you have a unique index.

> However, when I added most of the list yesterday I didn't get this error once even though a lot of the entries I added yesterday have a blank cell in column 2 as well. Whats going on?

That means that all these entries contain value `NULL`, not empty string `''`. Mysql lets you have multiple `NULL` values in unique fields.

Comment: @nutman, that's because `null = null` is `false` in SQL so 'duplicate' null's do not generate a hit in your query.

Comment: MySQL lets you have multiple `NULL` values in a unique field, only if the field is defined as `NULL`. If the field is defined as `NOT NULL`, no nulls at all are allowed.

Comment: @ypercube: I believe it's quite obvious. If column is `NOT NULL`, `NULL` values are not allowed regardless of `UNIQUE` or any other constraints.

Answer (score 1):

Check out your table index.
If that field got index (e.g. B+ tree index.) At that time update or insert query throws these kinds of error.

Remove indexing and then try to fire same query.

Answer (score 1):

Error 'Duplicate entry '338620-7' for key 2' on query. Default database

For this error :

```
set global sql_slave_skip_counter=1; 
start slave; 
show slave status\G
```

This worked for me

Answer (score 1):

you can try adding

```
$db['db_debug'] = FALSE;
```

in "your database file".php after that you can modify your database as you like.

Answer (score 0):

1. Drop the primary key first: (The primary key is your responsibility)

   ```
   ALTER TABLE Persons DROP PRIMARY KEY ;
   ```
2. Then make all insertions:
3. Add new primary key just like before dropping:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE Persons ADD PRIMARY KEY (P_Id);
   ```