# Need to check if mysql 1062 error occured and return a value to controller

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I need to check if a duplicate entry error occurred and if it occurred I need to return a value to my controller.

This is what i have done in my model

```
function ins($data)
{
    $this->load->database();
    if($this->db->insert('users',$data))
    {
        return "success";               
    }
    else
    {
        return "fail";
    }           
}
```

It doesn't work. How can I make it work?

Thank you

Comment: what´s the correct error it return by error php or console error

Comment: there is no console error.. I am stuck at the ins() function in the model with the error 1062

Comment: you don't insert Auto increment value

Comment: Your table id is autoincrement? Or maybe you have to expand the size in to your id if it is int 11 increment it to int 15

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL error - #1062 - Duplicate entry ' ' for key 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6153552/mysql-error-1062-duplicate-entry-for-key-2)

Comment: i have a unique field in my db. so the error will occur. What i need is when that error occur return a value back to my controller

Comment: my else part is not working..i am stuck in the model...i need to make the else part work