# Importing database (transfer wordpress site db)

Tags: sql, wordpress, phpmyadmin, web-hosting

I am moving a site from old godaddy hosting to new cpanel godaddy hosting.  I have downloaded Wordpress files using ftp, and downloaded sql database file as well.  When I go to my new hosting and try and import database I get this error...

x#1062 - Duplicate entry '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xEF\xBF\xBD\xEF\xBF\xBD' for key 'PRIMARY'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6153552/mysql-error-1062-duplicate-entry-for-key-2

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this answer is not about your error in particular but I think it can help you.

I humbly recommend you the Duplicator plug-in when moving WordPress sites. This plug-in will create a package for you which contains all your WordPress files and DB. It will also create a php installation file that will help you reinstall everything in very simple steps.

I've never experienced any issues moving WordPress sites with this plugin. Here's the link if you wanna give it a try.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/

Answer (score 0):

For the duplicate entry, if you have installed wordpress on the new panel then its because you have an administrator user with id 1 in the old database and in the new database as well that's why its showing duplicate entry.

The right thing for migration of wordress site is that you migrate it with 'All in one wp migration' plugin.
Manually move theme and plugins for time efficiency and export db with 'All in one wp migration' plugin.